# Is it possible to use 32 bit STS in 64 bit OS?

Tags: java, operating-system, spring-tool-suite

I am using 64 bit OS for my development and i want to use STS in my system i have only 32 bit sts, is it possible to use 32 bit sts in my 64 bit OS system ?

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to use 32 bit sts in my 64 bit OS system

Yes. But you must install a 32-bit version of Java.